# Camera records too slow in VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, camera

I just bought a USB LED digital microscope which works only on Windows XP/vista/7. To be able to use it on my Ubuntu machine, I installed virtualbox and created a virtual machine for Windows XP.

I installed the microscope's drivers (from the CD) and connected the microscope. When I tested the microscope, its camera was capturing too slow. It showed a black screen

[image]

for five minutes and after 5 minutes it captured this:

[image]

and stuck for another five minutes and did that again and so on. I also tested the digital microscope on another computer with windows and it worked just fine and fast.

Comment: I think this is more of a virtual box bug than anything else

Comment: If you set your VM to use 2 CPU's, and 2048 memory, does that help it run better?

Comment: It didnt work eventually...how can i fix it?my camera (not only the microscope but my webcam as well) is capturing too slow...